# Scala, Play framework. REST request to Google Custom Search Engine

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm new to Scala and Play Framework, and trying to learn them by doing small tasks. 
 Now i'm stuck on how to make GET request to CSE of Google.
Usual GET-request i can do like this :

```
     val requestUrl = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"

     val holder: WSRequestHolder = WS.url(requestQuery)
     val futureResponce: Future[WSResponse] =  holder.get()

     futureResponce.onComplete {
           case Success(resp) => println(resp.body)
           case Failure(thr) => println(thr.printStackTrace())
         }
```

This prints mocked JSON to console. 
Problem is when i change  requestUrl to

```
     val requestQuery = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_CSE_CODE&cx=MY_CX&q=cats"
```

I'm receiving 
 `[IOException: Remotely Closed]()`

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Do you need to use some other sort of authentication? A client or ca certificate?

Comment: I think it must work just like this, because from browser it works fine.